# Fullcalendar eventReceive disable time slot

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I would like to disabled slot time on drag and drop event when the slot has been already taken. How could I make it work?

I'm using Fulcalendar Event javascript and my event duration is only 15 minutes like this:

[image]

I checked the doc but didn't found how. I think I have to compare the title event already taken to blank in jQuery before accept the new drag and drop event if it's return true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `eventOverlap` option in fullCalendar, like this:

```
eventOverlap: false
```

This will mean that the UI will prevent events from being dragged or resized such that they fully or partially take up space occupied by an existing event.

See https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_ui/eventOverlap/ for more details.